# Print a "\" in sprintf using matlab

Tags: javascript, string, matlab, printf

What I am trying to do is write a script in Matlab that will parse some HTML, get some data out of it, take this data, and then format it into a Javascript string array. I do not have a problem grabbing HTML and parsing it and so forth, I am having trouble trying to print a string using `sprintf` that will contain a backslash.

Basically if you have a string in Javascript that contains a quotation mark you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
var string1 = "Here is a \"string\" example";
```

When I try to do this in Matlab as follows, it does not print correctly:

```
>> A = sprintf('Here is a \"string\" example')
A =
    Here is a "string" example
```

This is not a valid Javascript string. So basically I want `sprintf` to return a proper Javascript string; any suggestions?

I have tried using `\\"` and `\\\"` and a few similar combinations, all to no avail.

Comment: @twerdster is correct, [Strings](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strings.html) are defined with single quotation marks and for inserting a backslash: [formatting doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html): To insert a backslash, use \\

Comment: OK, we got off on the wrong foot here. I was just annoyed with how sloppy you had phrased the question/formatting, it was the end of a long day, etc., etc. So: apologies. If it helps: I was not trying to make myself feel better, I was *trying* to make you a better programmer; which includes good documentation skills.

Comment: Now, back to your question: judging from your comments, it seems this is a case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Can you show us how you "hacked" around it, so that we can solve the actual problem, not your take to the solution to it? Also, have you seen [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/08/20/get-html-table-data-into-matlab/)?

Comment: My solution was to not use sprintf, I found that it was not necessary for what I wanted. I ended up using simple string concatenation and regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab uses the reference Kernighan, B. W., and D. M. Ritchie, The C Programming Language for its sprintf function. According to the reference, the way sprintf is defined, it uses escape character as a way to overcome the default control meaning of characters.

Although you asked not to suggest the combination like

```
\"

\\\"
```

here is the viable solution where you don't have to manually replace the \" with \\" and the code does this action itself.

```
a = "Here is a \"string\" example";
d = regexprep(a,"\"","\\\"");
sprintf(d);
```

Comment: Strings in Matlab are single-quoted, double quotes have no syntactic meaning in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sprintf('Here is a \\"string\\" example.')
```

On my machine this outputs

```
Here is a \"string\" example.
```

Comment: For some reason that is not working for me properly. It may be because I am trying to do it combined with string concatenation and also printing to a file. I don't know. I was able to work around it in a kind of hack way, but whatever.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: Can you show us this hack way? Perhaps we can help you solve the issue instead of work around it